# Force resetting of values on another bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a parent window associated with one bean and child dialog(containing list) associated with another bean.

My requirement is whenever I click on link to open child dialog, I need to forcefully reset the list(Object) cleared.

Tried with the following in parent bean, but didn't work.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

childBean = (ChildBean) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext,
            "#{childBean}", ChildBean.class);   childBean.setEmployeeList(null);
```

using primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.0

Comment: Please post some relevant code, and tell what is the scope of those beans. Are you opening new window, or just using primefaces dialog, it is not clear to me?

Comment: Bean in View scope. Yes I'm using primefaces p:dialog

Comment: Not shore, yous should post more code. Are you shore that `setEmployeeList()` is not called? Maybe you just didn't updated some component?